# program on arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

```
System.out.println("Enter the appointment ID to see the full details :");
int y=in.nextInt();
int r;
for(r=0;r<count;r++)
{
    if(all.get(r).getID()==y)
    {
         all.get(r).display();
    }
}
```

I am using this code to retrieve the full details that have been entered using the get statement and display function. This is a small part of my program. I was wondering is there any other way to do it

Answer (score 4):

A better way would be to use a `HashMap<Integer,DetailsClass>` instead of an ArrayList.

Then, instead of a loop, you'll just write :

```
HashMap<Integer,DetailsClass> map = new HashMap<>();

...

if (map.containsKey(y)) {
    DetailsClass details = map.get(y);
    details.display();
}
```

This makes the code simpler and more efficient, since searching for a key in a HashMap takes expected constant time, while searching the List takes linear time.

If you must use an `ArrayList`, at least leave the loop once you find the object you were looking for :

```
int y=in.nextInt();
for(int r=0;r<count;r++)
{
    if(all.get(r).getID()==y)
    {
         all.get(r).display();
         return; // or break; depending on where this for loop is located
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to use array list (it is mandatory). want to know if there is any way to retrieve data other than the above all.get(r).display();

Comment: @ranjitkumar In that case, you have no choice but iterating over the ArrayList. There are shorter ways to write it using Java 8 streams, but if you are not allowed to use HashMap, I wouldn't use Streams either.

Comment: Generally calling `containsKey` followed by `get` is considered bad practice.

Comment: is there any scope of change (which would give me more ways of using get )

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree that it can be replaced with a single call to `get()`, but in such a simple program, I don't see the point in optimizing it. The OP is not allowed to use HashMap anyway, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Never loop over a `List` by index. You don't know what the internal implementation of the `List` is and looping might result on `O(n^2)` complexity.

I would suggest the following:

```
System.out.println("Enter the appointment ID to see the full details :");
final int y = in.nextInt();
for(final Thing thing : all) {
    if(thing.getID() == y) {
         thing.display();
    }
}
```

Or, if you can use Java 8, then:

```
all.stream()
        .filter(t -> t.getID() == y)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(Thing::display);
```

Comment: The title of the question does say it's an ArrayList, so you have random access.

Comment: @Eran that I know, but its an awful habit and worth breaking.

Comment: i want to try the code System.out.println("Enter the appointment ID to see the full details :");
final int y = in.nextInt();
for(final Thing thing : all) {
    if(thing.getID() == y) {
         thing.display();
    }
} but not sure what the (final Thing thing : all) statement (do not get angry i am new to java)

Comment: can any one help me in understanding the way the suggested code by Boris the Spider works

Comment: Was going to upvote. Then I noticed the `final` shtick.

Comment: @ranjitkumar It's a for-each loop. See here for more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Comment: @shmosel what have you got against `final`?

Comment: can i post my code so that it would be easy to follow your suggestions

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's not very standard (in method scope), and it doesn't add anything to the answer besides making a statement about your coding preferences.

Comment: @shmosel I disagree, but you're of course entitled to an opinion. I would argue _everything_ we write is a statement about our coding preferences. Placement of brackets, naming of variables, usage of whitespace. Every single thing,..

Comment: is is myeclipse considered as an automatic code-writing tool? if so why